# Restrict Login Email with Google OAuth2.0 to Specific Domain Name

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to restrict the login to my web application (which uses OAuth2.0 and Google APIs) to only accept authentication requests from users with an email on a specific domain name or set of domain names. I would like to whitelist as opposed to blacklist.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this, documentation on the officially accepted method of doing so, or an easy, secure work around?

For the record, I do not know any info about the user until they attempt to log in through Google's OAuth authentication. All I receive back is the basic user info and email.

Comment: I'm researching this also. I have an app that I want to be only accessible by people who have an account on our google apps for business domain. The google OpenID implementation may be more appropriate for both of us...

Comment: How can I implement domain user login using google sdk  and c#?

Comment: Please can some one look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220051/oauth2-restrict-to-emails-with-specfic-domain-name-using-hd-not-working

Comment: Please i have an oben bounty on that question so can some one help me

Answer (score 47):

So I've got an answer for you. In the OAuth request you can add `hd=example.com` and it will restrict authentication to users from that domain (I don't know if you can do multiple domains). You can find hd parameter documented [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#hd-param)

I'm using the Google API libraries from here: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2 so I had to manually edit the `/auth/apiOAuth2.php` file to this:

```
public function createAuthUrl($scope) {
    $params = array(
        'response_type=code',
        'redirect_uri=' . urlencode($this->redirectUri),
        'client_id=' . urlencode($this->clientId),
        'scope=' . urlencode($scope),
        'access_type=' . urlencode($this->accessType),
        'approval_prompt=' . urlencode($this->approvalPrompt),
        'hd=example.com'
    );

    if (isset($this->state)) {
        $params[] = 'state=' . urlencode($this->state);
    }
    $params = implode('&', $params);
    return self::OAUTH2_AUTH_URL . "?$params";
}
```

I'm still working on this app and found this, which may be the more correct answer to this question. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/

Comment: I wasn't aware of this parameter, can you link to where you found out about it?

Comment: Unfortunately I had to get the info from a colleague of mine, I didn't find this anywhere in google's docs.

My coworker thinks he found the reference in the OpenID spec and tried it out here in the OpenAuth spec and it seems to work. Use with caution I suppose since it seems to be undocumented functionality.

Comment: Important Note: Even though you are specifying an `hd` parameter in the `createAuthUrl` function, you will still need to verify that the user is logging in with your domain email address.  It's very easy to change the link parameter to allow all email addresses and subsequently gain access to your application.

Comment: I did a similar hack to set the loginHint (user email), which also if contains a hosted domain will redirect to the SAML login.  Unfortunately I hadnt found this thread first and didnt know about the hd parameter.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653680/google-api-allow-connections-only-with-google-apps-domain/19691368#19691368

Comment: The hd param does absolutely nothing for me.

Comment: The hd was working for a while but it suddenly stopped,so is there another solution

Comment: Hm, not that I know about. I'm not working on any apps that use this feature anymore so I haven't had to dig into it. It might warrant a new question on SO since this answer seems to be outdated and wrong

Comment: For the Google Documentation on the `hd` parameter usage see https://developers.google.com/identity/work/it-apps And the reference of the `hd` URI parameter can be found https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#authenticationuriparameters In synopsis, the `hd` param should be viewed as a domain based display filter for the Google Auth side, but should still be validated on your side.

Comment: Great, Currently, in `hd` parameter, I can only restrict one domain, Now what if I want to restrict two or three domains?

Comment: Answer by @JBithell also works well... if using the PHP library just use $client->setHostedDomain('yourdomain.com')

Answer (score 13):

## Client Side:

Using the `auth2` init function, you can pass the `hosted_domain` parameter to restrict the accounts listed on the signin popup to those matching your `hosted_domain`. You can see this in the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference

## Server Side:

Even with a restricted client-side list you will need to verify that the `id_token` matches the hosted domain you specified. For some implementations this means checking the `hd` attribute you receive from Google after verifying the token.

### Full Stack Example:

#### Web Code:

```javascript
gapi.load('auth2', function () {
    // init auth2 with your hosted_domain
    // only matching accounts will show up in the list or be accepted
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: "your-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        hosted_domain: 'your-special-domain.example'
    });

    // setup your signin button
    auth2.attachClickHandler(yourButtonElement, {});

    // when the current user changes
    auth2.currentUser.listen(function (user) {
        // if the user is signed in
        if (user && user.isSignedIn()) {
            // validate the token on your server,
            // your server will need to double check that the
            // `hd` matches your specified `hosted_domain`;
            validateTokenOnYourServer(user.getAuthResponse().id_token)
                .then(function () {
                    console.log('yay');
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    auth2.then(function() { auth2.signOut(); });
                });
        }
    });
});
```

#### Server Code (using googles Node.js library):

If you're not using Node.js you can view other examples here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

```javascript
const GoogleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
const Auth = new GoogleAuth();
const authData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(your_auth_creds_json_file));
const oauth = new Auth.OAuth2(authData.web.client_id, authData.web.client_secret);

const acceptableISSs = new Set(
    ['accounts.google.com', 'https://accounts.google.com']
);

const validateToken = (token) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!token) {
            reject();
        }
        oauth.verifyIdToken(token, null, (err, ticket) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            const payload = ticket.getPayload();
            const tokenIsOK = payload &&
                  payload.aud === authData.web.client_id &&
                  new Date(payload.exp * 1000) > new Date() &&
                  acceptableISSs.has(payload.iss) &&
                  payload.hd === 'your-special-domain.example';
            return tokenIsOK ? resolve() : reject();
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 9):

When defining your provider, pass in a hash at the end with the 'hd' parameter. You can read up on that here. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect#hd-param

E.g., for config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, 'identifier', 'key', {hd: 'yourdomain.com'}
```

Comment: This can easily be circumvented giving access to login with other domains. It will only work for limiting the available accounts shown to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did using passport in node.js. `profile` is the user attempting to log in.

```
//passed, stringified email login
var emailString = String(profile.emails[0].value);
//the domain you want to whitelist
var yourDomain = '@google.com';
//check the x amount of characters including and after @ symbol of passed user login.
//This means '@google.com' must be the final set of characters in the attempted login 
var domain = emailString.substr(emailString.length - yourDomain.length);

//I send the user back to the login screen if domain does not match 
if (domain != yourDomain)
   return done(err);
```

Then just create logic to look for multiple domains instead of just one. I believe this method is secure because 1. the '@' symbol is not a valid character in the first or second part of an email address. I could not trick the function by creating an email address like `mike@fake@google.com` 2. In a traditional login system I could, but this email address could never exist in Google. If it's not a valid Google account, you can't login.

Answer (score 2):

Since 2015 there has been a [function in the library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/dee3a8b840d87635b0e26da63202b163512f2d4e/src/Google/Client.php#L630) to set this without needing to edit the source of the library as in the [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11001585/3088158) by aaron-bruce

Before generating the url just call `setHostedDomain` against your Google Client

```
$client->setHostedDomain("HOSTED DOMAIN")
```

Answer (score 0):

For login with Google using Laravel Socialite
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/socialite#optional-parameters

```php
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

return Socialite::driver('google')
    ->with(['hd' => 'pontomais.com.br'])
    ->redirect();
```