# Need to redirect to google app email login page instead of normal gmail login in passportjs and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I have a nodejs application. In which I setup a google auth2 login system using passport js.
I need to authenticate against a google app email id not a normal gmail id. Authentication is working fine. But it is not redirecting to the google app email login page (google.com/a/domain.com). It redirect to the gmail login page and from there I can login and authenticate by typing the full email id (username@domain.com). Is there any way to redirect to app engine login page so that I have only needed to type the username only.

Comment: Have you looked at the extra parameters Google accepts, as I explained with your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543695/passportjs-authentication-using-google-apps-email-id/15544665#15544665)? I don't know if those will forward you to an app-specific page, though.

Comment: That is not worked for me, I am restricting to my domain by explicitly checking the "hd" parameter value inside my code. The redirection also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by editing this file

node_modules/passport-google-oauth/lib/passport-oauth/strategies/oauth2.js

I added a new line in line 164
below the following 2 lines
params['response_type'] = 'code';
params['redirect_uri'] = callbackURL;

new line is given below
params['hd'] = "domainname.com";

Now it is redirecting to the domain specific login page