# Customize (using my own google apps domain) the oauth SeviceLogin

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-apps, google-oauth

I'm wondering something... about my google apps domain.

I'm using the OAuth 2.0 as client side.

For now, i'm requesting an access token using this url "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?". If the user isn't connected to his google account he is redirected to a page like this : https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=lso&passive=1209600&continue=xxxxxxxxxx.......

but i want to use my custom page (using my google apps domain). I try manually to do what i want and that working (https://www.google.com/a/mydomain.com/ServiceLogin?service=lso&passive=1209600&continue=xxxxxxxxxx.......) but i don't know i can i do it programmatically...

Does anyone done what i'm trying to do ?

Regards,
Sebastien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the hd=example.com parameter to the initial request.

See:
[Restrict Login Email with Google OAuth2.0 to Specific Domain Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858813/restrict-login-email-with-google-oauth2-0-to-specific-domain-name)