# Google Sign in: Specific Domain

Tags: php, wordpress, google-signin

I want to create a microsite for a product that is not yet in GA / Public.

The only folks I want to have access to the content of the site are the people in my company that have a specific domain in their email address.

Those addresses would follow this format:

firstname.lastname@nameofdomain.com
and
firstname.lastname@nameofdomainvariant.com

Ideally I would create this site in Wordpress and use the Authorization portal to redirect to the correct index.php.

I have been looking at the following resources but I cant determine if they are the correct solutions:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/setting-google-authorship-website

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Any advice??

Answer (score 4):

Follow examples at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in and add following meta tag:

```
<meta name="google-signin-hosted_domain" content="nameofdomain.com">
```

You can also pass **hosted_domain** as [gapi.auth2.init parameter](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2initwzxhzdk20paramswzxhzdk21).

Answer (score 1):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11001585/1166727) seems to do the trick by whitelisting acceptable user domains taken from their google signin.