# Restrict Login Email with Google OAuth2.0 to Specific Access Group

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-workspace

Going slightly deeper in user restriction than [Restrict Login Email with Google OAuth2.0 to Specific Domain Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858813/restrict-login-email-with-google-oauth2-0-to-specific-domain-name), I would like to be able to restrict access to a specific [access group, also called email groups on GSuite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9050643?hl=en).

Our organisation manages different types of users, which are on different access groups. Each group is identified by an email group1@organization.com which both a distribution list and a set of users {user1; ... ; userN}.

We would like to provide access to some apps and sites using Google OAuth 2.0 and restrict access to some groups such as group1@organization.com

What's the procedure to achieve this?

Comment: Did you find an answer for your above question ? i'm trying do the same and try to restrict access of an app to specific google group

Comment: Not yet sorry. Still working on this.